Power BI Data Modelling - select dish based on the ingredients available
Not sure if this is possible in Power BI, I have a table with Dish and Ingredients. I want to create a filter on what ingredients are available so that I can then make the Dish.
If I filter on [Flour] I want to only see [Apple Pie] and [Pizza]. If I filter on [Tomato Sauce] I want to see [Pasta] and [Pizza].



Dish
Ingredients




Apple pie
apples, sugar, flour, eggs


Pasta
spaghetti, tomato sauce


Pizza
flour, tomato sauce, cheese



I thought of creating a fact table as below:



Dish
Ingredients




Apple pie
apples


Apple pie
sugar


Apple pie
slour


Apple pie
eggs


Pasta
spaghetti


Pasta
tomato sauce


Pizza
flour


Pizza
tomato sauce


Pasta
cheese



And a dim table as below and linking it to the fact table, but it is not returning the expected result. If I select tomato sauce and spaghetti, I only want to see Pasta, but I also see Pizza.



Ingredients




apples


sugar


flour


eggs


spaghetti


tomato sauce


cheese




I would use if() and sumproduct() - if() to leave the dish blank if not possible and sum product to check if each ingredient has a sufficient count exceeding the quantity needed...

Do you want to see all the dishes listed before applying filters, or you want the dishes to show up as you select the ingredients?

By default, Power BI slicers apply OR logic to your visuals, and not AND logic.
To change that, you need to create a DAX measure:
IsDishFiltered = 
IF (ISFILTERED(Ingredients[Ingredients]),
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( Ingredients[Ingredients] )
            && MAX ( Dishes[Ingredients] )
                IN ALLSELECTED ( Ingredients[Ingredients] )
                    && COUNTROWS ( Ingredients )
                        <= CALCULATE (
                            COUNT ( Dishes[Ingredients] ),
                            FILTER (
                                ALLSELECTED ( Dishes ),
                                [Ingredients]
                                    IN ALLSELECTED ( Ingredients[Ingredients] )
                                        && [Dish] = MAX ( 'Dishes'[Dish] )
                            )
                        ),
        1
    ),
1)

If you don't want your dishes to show up until you have filtered the ingredients, remove the first and last rows.
Finally, apply this measure as a filter in the visual where you want to display the dishes.

